# In CMake how do I make `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` suppress warnings from 3rd party library code?

Tags: c++, cmake, include, warnings, suppress-warnings

In CMake, you can make `TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES()` add include directories as *system* include directories (i.e. use `-isystem`) in order to not let warnings pop up which have their root in 3rd party code:

```
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(mytarget
    SYSTEM
        ${3rdPartyLib_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I prefer to use `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` which also makes include directories from 3rd party libraries available. 
As far as I know, `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` does not support the `SYSTEM` modifier to add those directories as a system include directories.

Did I get something wrong?

Is there a way to make:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mytarget
    ${3rdPartyLib_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

use `-isystem`? (or any other way to suppress warnings from `3rdPartyLib`).

Comment: yes, create a psuedo-target to model the imported library and its dependencies. Then target_link_libraries that target. 
For example, see the findboost.cmake script and note how the boost libraries are represented by targets such as Boost::boost, Boost::system etc.
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake

Comment: Rather than *suppress* warnings from 3rd party library it would be a better idea to *isolate* them by implementing façade library of some sort.

Comment: That might be an option in some cases but not if you would have to create a facade for Boost and/or Qt - for small programs this would be about 95% boiler plate facade code vs 5% own code I guess. In this case I'd rather declare `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES()` incomplete and use `TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake: target\_link\_libraries include as SYSTEM to suppress compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135983/cmake-target-link-libraries-include-as-system-to-suppress-compiler-warnings)

Comment: `target_link_libraries` links to library targets. It doesn't make sense to pass it include directories.

Answer (score 6):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136398/1523730), which I solved with a custom function:

```
function(target_link_libraries_system target)
  set(libs ${ARGN})
  foreach(lib ${libs})
    get_target_property(lib_include_dirs ${lib} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    target_include_directories(${target} SYSTEM PRIVATE ${lib_include_dirs})
    target_link_libraries(${target} ${lib})
  endforeach(lib)
endfunction(target_link_libraries_system)
```

I can now call `target_link_libraries_system(myapp lib::lib)` and the include directories are read from the target's properties.

This could now be extended to specify the `PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE` scope but since I use it on an executable, this is sufficient for now.

Comment: Note: this will not work with [generated properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#path-expressions). For that you have to do `target_include_directories(${target} SYSTEM PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${lib},INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>>")`, since the properties will not be available at "cmake time". You may want to change `BUILD_INTERFACE` to something else, see link.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you create a header named `myproject_thirdparty.h` that look like this:

```
#ifndef myproject_thirdparty_h
#define myproject_thirdparty_h

#include "myprojectMacros.h"

CLANG_PRAGMA_PUSH
CLANG_SUPPRESS_Wfloat_equal
CLANG_PRAGMA_POP

#endif
```

where `myprojectMacros.h` would define useful macros like `CLANG_PRAGMA_PUSH`, `CLANG_PRAGMA_POP`, `GCC_PRAGMA_PUSH`, `GCC_PRAGMA_POP`, ...

For example of such macro, see https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/6b41fe1cbf7a71a6003d4824e02a69b41a508cda/Modules/Core/Common/include/itkMacro.h#L69-L136

Then, within your project code, you would then include `myproject_thirdparty_h` each time you would like to use the library, this would effectively shutdown the warnings without impacting the remaining of your project.