# CMake: target_link_libraries include as SYSTEM to suppress compiler warnings

Tags: cmake

To suppress compiler warnings that originate from libraries I use in my application, I manually include their directories with `target_include_directories(myapp SYSTEM ...)` as system libraries before adding them with `target_link_libraries` like so:

```
add_executable(myapp myapp.cpp)
target_include_directories(myapp SYSTEM
  PRIVATE "extern/lib/include"
)
target_link_libraries(myapp lib::lib)
```

However, that kind of feels hacky and will also break if the developers of `lib` decide to change the include path. This wouldn't be a problem if using only `target_link_library` but then, of course, they are included via `-I` and again I would get compiler warnings coming from this include.

Is there any more elegant and fail-safe way of doing this? It would be great if `target_link_libraries` had a `SYSTEM` option to tell cmake to include it as a system library.

Comment: I don't remember exactly since it is a few years ago, but I probably didn't see 51816807 at first, otherwise I would obviously have not created this question. I guess while I was in the process of solving my own question, I stumbled across 51816807 at some point when it was too late, so I also replied there. I didn't want to hijack that question, didn't have any bad intentions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I did my research before asking the question, I always do. Maybe I just queried the wrong search terms, I don't remember, it's been 4 years. Maybe the now-obvious duplicate (or this question) had different titles or text body than today, so the questions weren't clear duplicates back then.

Answer (score 16):

I defined a function to handle this for me:

```
function(target_link_libraries_system target)
  set(libs ${ARGN})
  foreach(lib ${libs})
    get_target_property(lib_include_dirs ${lib} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    target_include_directories(${target} SYSTEM PRIVATE ${lib_include_dirs})
    target_link_libraries(${target} ${lib})
  endforeach(lib)
endfunction(target_link_libraries_system)
```

I can now call `target_link_libraries_system(myapp lib::lib)` and the include directories are read from the target's properties.

This can be extended to optionally specify the `PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE` scope:

```
function(target_link_libraries_system target)
  set(options PRIVATE PUBLIC INTERFACE)
  cmake_parse_arguments(TLLS "${options}" "" "" ${ARGN})
  foreach(op ${options})
    if(TLLS_${op})
      set(scope ${op})
    endif()
  endforeach(op)
  set(libs ${TLLS_UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS})

  foreach(lib ${libs})
    get_target_property(lib_include_dirs ${lib} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    if(lib_include_dirs)
      if(scope)
        target_include_directories(${target} SYSTEM ${scope} ${lib_include_dirs})
      else()
        target_include_directories(${target} SYSTEM PRIVATE ${lib_include_dirs})
      endif()
    else()
      message("Warning: ${lib} doesn't set INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES. No include_directories set.")
    endif()
    if(scope)
      target_link_libraries(${target} ${scope} ${lib})
    else()
      target_link_libraries(${target} ${lib})
    endif()
  endforeach()
endfunction(target_link_libraries_system)
```

This extended version will also print a warning if a library didn't set its `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property.

Comment: That's gorgeous! Really helped me. It is worth noticing that this function will also work applied to libraries imported via Hunter.

Comment: It seems that this is not working for projects generated for Visual Studio?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for transitive dependencies. I can fix it by adding dependencies on my transitive dependencies, but that's not as cool.

Comment: @kiki "SYSTEM" is currently broken in the cmake Visual Studio generator ( https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18272# )

Answer (score 6):

To start with, you haven't specified whether your target that you're linking to is [`IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) or not. I'm assuming that it is `IMPORTED` because include directories for `IMPORTED` targets are `SYSTEM` by default. Note: This behaviour can be disabled. Pre-CMake v3.25, one would use one of [`NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html) or  [`IMPORTED_NO_SYSTEM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_NO_SYSTEM.html). For CMake 3.25 and later, one would modify the [`SYSTEM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SYSTEM.html) property of the target.

That typically just leaves the cases of targets added via `add_subdirectory`, which includes those added by `FetchContent` in its non-`find_package` mode. In that case, you can see the [`FetchContent` Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64064157/11107541), and the [`add_subdirectory` Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74020789/11107541). In summary, for pre-CMake v3.25, use a workaround in which you copy/move the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property to the `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property, and for CMake v3.25 or later, you can modify the `SYSTEM` target property, or the `SYSTEM` directory property, or use the `SYSTEM` argument of `add_subdirectory`/`FetchContent_Declare`.

Comment: the add_subdirectory Q&A is gone :(

Comment: @Fadeway I was the author of it and I deleted it because it got downvoted and honestly didn't add much of useful value on top of what is already written here.

Answer (score 4):

I modified Sebastian's solution to include the scope.

```
function(target_link_libraries_system target scope)
  set(libs ${ARGN})
  foreach(lib ${libs})
    get_target_property(lib_include_dirs ${lib} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    target_include_directories(${target} SYSTEM ${scope} ${lib_include_dirs})
    target_link_libraries(${target} ${scope} ${lib})
  endforeach(lib)
endfunction(target_link_libraries_system)
```

Comment: Since I now was in the situation where I needed this, I implemented a version with optional keyword handling. Thanks for the inspiration ;)

Answer (score 3):

This was asked in the [CMake discourse](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/declare-imported-targets-as-system-to-suppress-warnings/555) and @ben.boeckel (CMake developer) answered:

> IMPORTED targets should already have their include directories
> treated as SYSTEM though. There is the NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED target
> property to disable it.

Comment: True, but unfortunately apparently this is not working with the visual studio generator: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20422 and https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18272
I think this is why this question was asked on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Possible gotcha: If you are like me, and start every project by enabling all warnings in the toplevel directory…

```
# Warning level
add_compile_options(
    -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic

    -Werror=switch
    -Werror=return-type
    -Werror=uninitialized
    -Werror=format-security
    -Werror=reorder
    -Werror=delete-non-virtual-dtor
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-Werror>
)
```

… then, this obviously gets inherited by all subprojects (like git submodules, or what have you).

If *this* is the case, the solution is simple – be specific: Do it in a subdirectory, and/or use `target_compile_options`, for good measure:

```
target_compile_options(myTarget PRIVATE
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined a function which will declare a library as a system library, and handle all the include tagging itself.

```
function(declare_system_library target)
  message(STATUS "Declaring system library ${target}")
  get_target_property(target_aliased_name ${target} ALIASED_TARGET)
  if (target_aliased_name)
    set(target ${target_aliased_name})
  endif()
  set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES $<TARGET_PROPERTY:${target},INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
endfunction()
```

All this function does is add the target's include directories to it's system include directories.

For example, calling `declare_system_library(fmt::fmt)` will mean the include directories for the `fmt::fmt` library are now system libraries, allowing me to freely link against this library without worrying about declaring it system every time.

```
declare_system_library(fmt::fmt)

add_executable(my_exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_exe PRIVATE fmt::fmt)

// NOT NEEDED
// get_target_property(fmt_include_dirs fmt::fmt INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
// target_include_directories(my_exe SYSTEM PRIVATE ${lib_include_dirs})
```