# Ignore `Wunused-parameter` for 3rd party headers

Tags: c++, cmake

I use `Wunused-parameter` for my project, but I want to have it ignore 3rd party headers (headers in specific directories). Is there a way I can set this with `cmake`?

I'm currently setting the compiler options like this:

```
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -pedantic-errors -Wshadow -Wstrict-aliasing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers generally ignore warnings in system headers. So, the solution is to designate the directories where the third party headers are searched from as system include directories.

In GCC / Clang, this is achieved by using `-isystem` instead of `-I`, In Cmake, this is done by passing the argument `SYSTEM` to `target_include_directories`.

However, include dirs of third party libraries are typically added using `target_link_libraries` instead and unfotunately there is no way to pass SYSTEM through that directly. This can be solved with a little helper function: [CMake: target_link_libraries include as SYSTEM to suppress compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52136398/2079303).