# Is there a way to get -isystem for FetchContent targets?

Tags: cmake, include, clang-tidy

[`NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html) tells us that `IMPORTED` targets automagically get `-isystem`. Does that also hold for targets introduced to the project with [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html)?

If not (I assume so due to having problems with clang-tidy warnings on fetched targets), what is the best way to get `-isystem` for such targets?

Comment: `FetchContent` provides you the project's sources which you include with `add_subdirectory`. Since the project defines (usually) normal (non-IMPORTED) targets, they doesn't have `SYSTEM` property. "what is the best way to get `-isystem` for such targets?" - Build the project **separately** from your main project. In the main project you may use `find_package` for include the project which is built. That way you will have `IMPORTED` target, which is accompanied with `SYSTEM` include directories.

Comment: What you describe sounds like `ExternalProject_add`s ballpark and superbuild scripts. I was under the impression, that `FetchContent` was created to give access to external targets at config time, so at build time it is built like it would be part of your codebase. Now I just want to break that "bonding" up again, and mark those targets as `SYSTEM` includes, but still have one big build. Does that make sense?

Comment: "... at build time it is built like it would be part of your codebase." - Yes, it is correct: a fetched project becomes part of your codebase. "mark those targets as SYSTEM includes" - CMake simply doesn't have such mark. You may try, however, to copy content of property [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) to [INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) one. This would effectively mark all include directories for target as SYSTEM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [`NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED.html) tells us that `IMPORTED` targets automagically get `-isystem`. Does that also hold for targets introduced to the project with [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html)?

No, because targets added by `FetchContent` are essentially added by `add_subdirectory`: they become targets to *build* (instead of just *import*) in the generated buildystem.

> If not (I assume so due to having problems with clang-tidy warnings on fetched targets), what is the best way to get -isystem for such targets?

If you are using [CMake 3.25](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.25.html) (`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)`), you can use the `SYSTEM` argument of [`FetchContent_Declare`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html), which was added in [merge request #7399 by contributor daquexian](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/7399).

For users of CPM, I have given the CPM authors a heads up about this change [here](https://github.com/cpm-cmake/CPM.cmake/issues/377).

There is also the new [`SYSTEM` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SYSTEM.html), which was added in [merge request #7308 (also by daquexian)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/7308). If `SYSTEM` is `ON`, the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will be treated as system include directories.

If your `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ...)` is less than v3.25, then use [this other answer](/a/64139281).

Answer (score 6):

It is actually really easy (kudos to @Tsyvarev):

```
include (FetchContent)

set (FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

FetchContent_Declare (
  Catch2
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
  GIT_TAG v2.4.2
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable (Catch2)

### here is what makes all include directories -isystem
get_target_property(CATCH2_IID Catch2 INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
set_target_properties(Catch2 PROPERTIES INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CATCH2_IID}")
```

Comment: What about libraries like Catch2 v3 which get compiled first?

Comment: I'd say it will just get built? Did you encounter any issues?