# Suppress compiler warnings from external library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build the following project https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr#cmake into my project by following their instructions for CMake reproduced below:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(cpr GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr.git GIT_TAG c8d33915dbd88ad6c92b258869b03aba06587ff9) # the commit hash for 1.5.0
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cpr)
```

My project already had some other libraries linked with the main target so I included this new library as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE cpr::cpr PUBLIC other_libraries)
```

The problem with this is that the warnings from building the `cpr` library are preventing the project from building. I would like to suppress these warnings. I have tried adding the `SYSTEM` keyword as recommended here: [How to suppress GCC warnings from library headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers) so the code would look as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE SYSTEM cpr::cpr PUBLIC other_libraries)
```

but this did not help. Are there other methods to suppress warnings from external libraries in CMake? If it helps, I am using `C++-17` `g++-11` and Ninja.

Comment: This would be a great feature to have for linux and cross-platform projects. Visual Studio 16.10 added this recently via an optional setting and including the external library with angle brackets: `#include <cpr>`.

Comment: "the warnings from **building** the `cpr` library are preventing the project from building" - So you get warnings only when compile `cpr` library itself, not when you include its headers? The library integrated with with `FetchContent` uses those compiler flags, which are set in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` at the time when `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` is called. Make sure these flags do not treat warning, emitted by the library, as errors.

Comment: Yes it is only when I try to compile the project. Could you elaborate a bit more on the compiler flags? These flags would be set based on cpr's CMake file right?

Comment: @nbadami, the important question is whether the warnings come when compiling `cpr/…something.cpp`, or when comping your own .cpp that includes something from `cpr/include`. Different mitigation is needed for each problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get -isystem for FetchContent targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064157/is-there-a-way-to-get-isystem-for-fetchcontent-targets)

Comment: `cpr` builds with zero warnings for me. What kind of warnings are you getting? Please provide at least one unedited complete warning.

Answer (score -1):

The only way around I could find was to disable warnings using compiler pragmas within the code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This is compiler dependent. If you use clang, simply replace "GCC" by "clang". On Visual Studio, use pragma warning... This can be made portable with macros, have a look at [this article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/08/30/how-to-disable-a-warning-in-cpp/).