# How to suppress compiler warnings for CUDA with CMake?

Tags: cmake, cuda

I have a project with both `CXX` and `CUDA` enabled:

```
project(my_proj LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
```

I am linking a third-party library, which uses another third-party library (`Eigen`) as a dependency. I am building with warnings turned on. When building a `*.cpp` file, I don't have warnings, but when building a `*.cu`, a warning inside `Eigen` is issued. I tried to follow the advice from here - [CMake: target_link_libraries include as SYSTEM to suppress compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135983/cmake-target-link-libraries-include-as-system-to-suppress-compiler-warnings) - but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Which version of Eigen are you using? I think they have added more diagnostic suppression pragmas in their code at some point. See [Issue 2331: Tons of warnings when use Eigen and CUDA concurrently.](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2331)

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/cms-sw/cmssw/issues/33369) and the linked merge request might also be of interest for seeing how others have dealt with the same issue, although w/o CMake. Seems like there is/was a compiler bug as well not accepting some diagnostic numbers in pragmas.

Comment: I don't know the version. As mentioned, in my case the `Eigen` is the dependency of a dependency and I don't have much control over it.

Comment: Depends on how it was installed. Your comment sounds like it comes completely encapsulated in the third-party library?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, you're right. In my case, the warning comes from the file `/usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/x86_64-linux/include/host_defines.h` which is used by (probably old) `Eigen`. There's a `#warning` pragma in the file.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure.  I was assuming you were thinking about suppressing warnings by ID.  But after I read your linked article, it appears to be another "suppression method" that I am unfamiliar with.  So I deleted by comment.

Answer (score 1):

With CMake 3.8 and later, CUDA is a first-class language (even if support is rough around the edges). So, the way to make the CUDA compiler behave differently is essentially the same way as for the compiler for C or C++ etc:

```
target_compile_options(my_cudaish_target some_flag another_flag etc);
```

assuming your CUDA compiler is NVCC, relevant flags might be `-w` to disable all warnings, or `-Wnofoo` for disabling a warning named `foo`.

Now, if you're building Eigen using its *own* `CMakeLists.txt`, then either you modify that, or you report a bug against Eigen to have its developers address the issue.

---

See also the following CMake documentation pages:

- [`target_compiler_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html#command:target_compile_options)
- [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_FLAGS)